# How to get what's using the COM Port Visual Basic (.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I have this code here

```
For i As Integer = 0 to My.Computer.Ports.SerialNames.Count - 1
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i))
Next
```

Example Output:

```
COM1
COM2
COM3
```

this returns a list of used COM ports in a ComboBox

now what I want to do is something like this

```
COM1 <USB Mouse>
COM2 <USB Keyboard>
```

etc.

I want to get whatever it is using the COM port.

Hope anyone can help, thanks!

Comment: That's not possible.  Serial ports are very primitive, they date from the stone-age of computing.  That's what you plugged your teletype into to start banging in your Fortran program.  It is missing all the goodies you'd get with USB, no play-and-play support at all.  So no way to find out what kind of device is attached to the other end of the wire.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/331a26c1-0f42-4cf1-8adb-32fb09a18953/

Comment: @SysDragon Thanks! I was trying something similar until I read your comment, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found a link where your question is solved: [Msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/331a26c1-0f42-4cf1-8adb-32fb09a18953/)

It uses Windows Management Instrumentation to retrieve the data you want from the ports. This way you will retrieve the full name of the port, including the part you want.

Here is the code:

```
' Add reference to System.Management.dll.
Try
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
   "root\cimv2", _
   "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort")

    For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
        MsgBox(queryObj("Name"))
    Next

Catch err As ManagementException
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
End Try
```